# Copying files from one server to another using a jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, server, jenkins-pipeline, scp, robocopy

I have a jenkins job running which is building an angular app using "**npm install**" and "**ng build**" now this job is creating a **dist** folder on server **1** and now I want to copy this **dist** folder to server **8** using jenkins job.
How can i accomplish this?

I tried everyting there is but its not working. Please guide me...

Comment: run scp or rsync ...

Comment: What did you try? "Everything" is not sufficient...

Comment: @RalfUlrich i tried remote shell, scp, robocopy, ssh agent, like everything. The issue might be because both servers have different network

Comment: There are several different tools that can be used to copy files from one host to another. And there are several reasons why these tools might fail. Your question is pretty vague about what actual problems you had. Please [edit] your question to describe specifically what you tried, and how it failed. Include the exact error messages that you got.

Comment: Then please add the result of running scp to your question: command used, error message.